# How to add each row value while iterating DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I got a DataGrid with filtering, and I want to get the total sum of each column in this grid. At this moment I have an iteration through the filtered DataGrid, but I have no idea how to access the numbers and add them together.

```cs
private void Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as System.Windows.Controls.Calendar;
    CollectionViewSource addedFoodsViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("addedFoodsViewSource")));

    if (tb == null)
    {
        fooddatabaseDataSet1.AddedFoodsDataTable dt = addedFoodsViewSource.Source as fooddatabaseDataSet1.AddedFoodsDataTable;
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = null;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        string txt = tb.SelectedDate.ToString();

        fooddatabaseDataSet1.AddedFoodsDataTable dt = addedFoodsViewSource.Source as fooddatabaseDataSet1.AddedFoodsDataTable;
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("AddedDate LIKE '%{0}%'", txt);
    }
    
    Int32 sum = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < addedFoodsDataGrid.Items.Count - 1; i++)
    { 

    }
}
```

Comment: You should bind a collectionview and sum the value of each property, as Arie is advising. Working with the UI to sum up values which are presented as strings is not a good plan.

Answer (score 0):

To get filtered data you don't use the `DataGrid` itself, you use the underlying `DataView`. You may iterate through the view itself:

```
foreach (DataRowView rowView in dt.DefaultView)
{
    var row = rowView.Row as AddedFoodsDataRow;
    // Do something //
}
```

... or export it to a table:

```
var filteredData = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

or, if you want the third column:

```
var sum = filteredData.AsEnumerable().Sum(x=>x.Field<int>(3));
```

or, if you want to access the column by name

```
var sum = filteredData.AsEnumerable().Sum(x=>x.Field<int>("SomeProperty"));
```

Comment: To be honest, i do not need to get this data. I need to get total sum of column of the grid. And I have a loop that iterate through every row, and I am trying to add each column cell value in this iteration to get total, but I do not know how.

Comment: but that's exactly what it does..? you just do: var sumOfColumnWithSomeProperty = filteredData.Sum(x=>x.SomeProperty);

Comment: But what if i want to print result in some textbox?

Comment: If you want to see the result in a textblock or textbox ( but editing a total value doesn't make much sense ) expose another public property from your datacontext's viewmodel and bind text of the textblock to that.  Either almost all teams somehow got it wrong or MVVM really is the best way to work with wpf.

Comment: I made something like this:
                string txt = tb.SelectedDate.ToString();

                fooddatabaseDataSet1.AddedFoodsDataTable dt = addedFoodsViewSource.Source as fooddatabaseDataSet1.AddedFoodsDataTable;
                dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("AddedDate LIKE '%{0}%'", txt);
                var filteredData = dt.DefaultView.ToTable() as fooddatabaseDataSet1.AddedFoodsDataTable;
                var sum = filteredData.Sum(x => x.AddedCalories);
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString());
            }
and it doesnt works, whats wrong

Comment: is it not compiling? is it not filtering? does it throw an exception? is the sum value wrong?

Comment: System.ArgumentNullException, when i click on any date in calendar

Comment: ah, I forgot that casting the result of dt.DefaultView.ToTable() to a strongly typed table won't work. I fixed my answer. I tested it and this works: var filteredData = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(); filteredData.AsEnumerable().Sum(x=>x.Field<int>("SomeProperty"));

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the sum of each column going through all the items and invoking **GetCellContent** method on particular column.
Here I assume that you have DataGridTextColumn to store your data.

```
    private long GetColumnSum(DataGridColumn column)
    {
        long result = 0;
        foreach (ItemCollection item in addedFoodsDataGrid.Items)
        {
            result += int.Parse((column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text);
        }
        return result;
    }
```